# React server side render - for dynamic component load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dynamic, components, server-side-rendering

Currently i am using [reactboilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) as base architecture.
Requirement is to build a dynamic component that loads on the fly. **Reactboilerplate** uses webpack2 which bundles all the components at build time and deploys the whole package. There is no room for Dynamic component to be loaded later point in time without bundling the component as part of the main project.

One option i explored is SSR, which solves the problem, but i am not sure how to fit SSR model with the architecture i am currently using.

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.